# anycable in a separate server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, go, actioncable

I have my rails in a server A and I created a separate server where Go-lang is installed

My Goal is to use Anycable-Go with Rails but being in separated server.

I can't really find any clear explanation in google how to do that, but from the [doc](https://docs.anycable.io/#/go_getting_started) I tried the following in my "Go" server :

```
go get -u -f github.com/anycable/anycable-go/cmd/anycable-go
```

then

```
anycable-go --rpc_host=0.0.0.0:50051 --headers=cookie,x-api-token \
              --redis_url=redis://{my_redis_username}:{my_redis_password}@{my_redis_machine_url} --redis_channel=anycable \
              --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8084
```

The output looks like this :

[image]

Am really not that sure am on the right track so far... but if so, how am supposed to make my rails app connect/using this "anycable-go" server ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `anycable-rails` gem to your app and run AnyCable RPC server (`bundle exec anycable`) along with the Rails server. See https://docs.anycable.io/#/using_with_rails